# terminating thread gracefully on main app termination

Tags: winapi

I have a modelless dialog that creates a thread, and if the cancel button in the dialog is hit,  a variable bCancel is set which the thread in question periodically checks, and then immediately jumps to its clean up code.  It works fine. I can even send a WM_COMMAND...ID_CANCEL to the dialog from other places and it works the same.  But its not working when I try to send ID_CANCEL to the dialog from the main application window's WM_CLOSE handler (i.e. the user is trying to shut the entire application down while this thread is running.) As best I can tell something is just terminating the thread from outside before it can execute its cleanup code. Does this sound right.  What can I do.

(There's a critical section in the dialog's ID_CANCEL handler I didn't mention - not sure how relevant it is.  (bCancel is set within this critical section and the thread executes its clean up code within the same critical section.)

Comment: Update your question and explain how you *know* that the clean-up code isn't getting executed.

Comment: Well, I put debug statements in it. Specifically though a directory wasn't getting deleted that is deleted at the end of the thread and gets deleted in every other instance that ID_CANCEL is sent to the dialog. I've tried WaitForSingleObject in the dialog ID_CANCEL handler (as suggested by CHris below) and the thread doesn't terminate if I wait for it like that - could be because the thread itself is setting control values of the dialog in its exit code. Maybe I need to run WaitForSingleObject in the WM_CLOSE Handler of the App's main window (and not in the Dialog code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that anyone's still interested, but in the main app WM_CLOSE handler I set bCloseApp=TRUE, then send ID_CANCEL to the dialog and then check if the thread is active.  If it is I return 0 (thus bypassing the default DestroyWindow of WM_CLOSE.) Then in the thread exit code I PostMessage(...WM_CLOSE...) to the main app window if bCloseApp==TRUE.

Before implementing the above I found that while in the main app's WM_CLOSE handler, the thread in question is automatically suspended for some reason (which surprised me)  and that was a complicating factor as I couldn't wait for the thread to terminate while in the WM_CLOSE handler.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the thread's bCancel, your dialog code should wait for the thread handle to get signaled (thus destroyed), so you can use one of the wait### functions on the thread handle (with a sane timeout value of course), thus the app will wait a tiny bit for your thread cleanup to get called.

Comment: Presume you mean WaitForSingleObject though never used it before.  Used CriticalSections and mutexes for various things though.

Comment: I'm not clear on what I'm waiting for - waiting for the thread to terminate?

Comment: Yes, after your code tells the thread to cancel it would immediately do a WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE), which will block until this thread ends.